# Can't find C++20 Integer Comparison Functions on Apple Clang

Tags: c++, clang

Currently using MacOS Monterey, Apple Clang 13.0.0, g++.

Although I am able to use the integer comparison functions such as `std::cmp_less` or `std::cmp_greater` from the `<utility>` header without any problems on WSL2, when I try it on my Macbook, the compiler tells me that the functions do not exist. Do I need to upgrade Clang? Or does Clang not support these functions yet?

Comment: Those functions were added in c++20, so you need a c++20 compliant compiler and appropriate flags to run it in c++20 mode.

Comment: I'm using these flags to compile my program: `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Weffc++ -Wsign-conversion -Werror`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems to work with 13.0.0 [here](https://godbolt.org/z/chjqcre95).

Comment: Not sure what standard library you are using, but that may need to be updated in order for your code to compile.

Comment: Is there a difference between Apple Clang and Clang? Could this be why its not working?

Comment: According to [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), you need/can use Clang v13 to have safe integral comparison support. So, this should work ...

Comment: Apple clang isn't normal clang and they don't really document exactly which version of clang it's based on

Comment: Per [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) there is no support for Safe integral comparisons in the C++20 library features section.  It probably has not yet been implemented.